# Can't alert javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to print the contents of my digest variable but not having any luck. The below is the code I have. I've read a few tutorials and can't see why it wouldn't work.

```
  // Store Credentials
  var userName = "username";
  var sharedSecret = "secret";

  // Build Header
    var date = new Date();
    var nonce = md5(Math.random());
    var nonce_ts = date.toISOString().replace(/(\.\d\d\dZ)/ ,'Z');
    var digest = (new Buffer(sha1(nonce + nonce_ts + sharedSecret)).toString('base64'));

  alert(digest);
```

It was taken from nodeJS and I am trying to make it javascript.

Comment: Is this Node.js? `Buffer` and `md5` aren't standard JS

Comment: This looks like NodeJS, NodeJS doesn't have a native alert function, try console.log

Comment: @Cerbrus Ok I think that is the problem. I took from nodeJS to try and make JS. Do I need to recreate this function in JS?

Comment: node (like a browser) has a JavaScript engine to run JS code. `alert`, `md5`, `Buffer` are not part of the JavaScript language specification, but are part of an API provided directly by the environment or by a foreign library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *It was taken from nodeJS and I am trying to make it JavaScript.*

Then you need to make sure `md5`, `sha1` and `Buffer` are ported over to your JavaScript environment. These aren't normally available in a browser.

The reason you're not getting an `alert` window, is because the code is crashing on those function. You can easily see that by opening your browser's developer console (Usually F12)

Comment: (I've found this library for [`Buffer`](https://github.com/feross/buffer), and another one for [`md5`](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5) and [`sha1`](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha1))